# How to scan docker image using JFrog XRay from Openshift pipeline

Tags: openshift, artifactory, jfrog-xray

I have docker image pushed to artifactory docker registry, JFrog XRay is up and running. 
I understand that to use XRay, it requires some build info passed to it (like buildName, buildNumber), which artifactory docker registry doesn't contain.

According to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-DockerBuildswithArtifactory I must have access to docker daemon (on jenkins agent itself or some other container). As far as I know running docker requires privileged access which is unsafe as it could compromise cluster security.

Is there any way to push docker build to XRay without docker daemon?

Comment: Looks like you got an answer here on how to scan a docker image with Xray, when the scanning is not part of CI/CD process. Are you interested in creating a build-info for the docker image and then scanning this build-info with Xray, from a machine which does not have a docker daemon running? If so, how was this docker image created or pulled onto this machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scan a Docker with Xray you don't have to add the build-info.
It is enough to define a Watch on the relevant Docker repository with the needed policies.

If you want to scan a Docker build as part of the build process, I suggest that you will contact JFrog Support and they will assist you with any relevant question.

Thanks,
Ofir - trying to help with Xray :-)